# Parse error when minifying JSON

Tags: json

I'm trying to minify this JSON:

```
“div” : {
    “attributes” : { “id” : “context-box-4” },
    “children” : {
        “h4” :{ “type” : “text” },
        “p” : { “numbers” : 4, “type” : “text”},
        “ul” : {
            “children” : {
                    “p” : { “type” : “text” },
                    “li” : { “numbers” : 3, “ type” : ”text” }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
        “div” : {       “attribu
--^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a valid JSON:

- Remove `“div” :`
- Replace `“` (`U+201C`) and `”` (`U+201D`) with `"` (`U+0022`)

The result will be:

```
{
    "attributes" : { "id" : "context-box-4" },
    "children" : {
        "h4" :{ "type" : "text" },
        "p" : { "numbers" : 4, "type" : "text"},
        "ul" : {
            "children" : {
                    "p" : { "type" : "text" },
                    "li" : { "numbers" : 3, " type" : "text" }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

When minifying:

```
{"attributes":{"id":"context-box-4"},"children":{"h4":{"type":"text"},"p":{"numbers":4,"type":"text"},"ul":{"children":{"p":{"type":"text"},"li":{"numbers":3," type":"text"}}}}}
```